# Qualtrics: I have a 2x2 matrix table, and I'm trying to generate a custom validation

Tags: regex, validation, qualtrics

I have a 2x2 matrix table question in qualtrics, each response option being a text box. I would like to only accept numerical responses. The two left columns can be any number. For the right two, they can be any number that is less than or equal to the respective box on the left, or a percentage. Having tried options, I'm not thinking tha this can only be done using matches regex option. This is new to me, so any help would be appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. In order the question to be understood, you need to share the relevant part of the code about what you have done so far, instead of sharing it as text. Also see: [https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks, I think I'm asking a double barrelled question which has complicated it too. However, I don't have any successful code. The main question Q1) can I force a response to be less than or equal to another response within the same matrix table, while forcing them to be numeric?

Answer (score 0):

You can't do it with Custom Validation. There isn't any way to reference a value on the same page in the right side of a validation condition.

You'll have to use JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks, sounds like it's beyond me then.